# Unable to Boot Ubuntu 12.04.5 VM running on Hyper-V 2012 R2

Tags: hyper-v, ubuntu-12.04

We have a VM running Ubuntu 12.04.5 which we're currently experiencing issues with that will not boot up correctly.

Based on my research it appears there are known issues with some storage drivers when running Ubuntu on Hyper-V which there are patches for.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1445195

However, I'm unsure how to go about applying these patches since we're not currently able to boot into the server.

Below are some screenshots showing the messages that appear while booting:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Result

Per [Windows Ninja's comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/724268/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-12-04-5-vm-running-on-hyper-v-2012-r2/724286#comment-902532) below, here was the root cause:

> I ended up getting the VM to boot by selecting an earlier kernel version (3.13.0-61). The problem is supposed to be patched in 3.13.0-62 but it didn't work in that version or 63 even though it did previously. I don't understand why reverting to this earlier version worked but it did.

Remainder of the original answer left in place in case it helps someone else out.

## Original Answer

If you can get to the Grub menu, then there is usually a recovery option that you can use to try to repair the system and possibly install the patch.

If you can't get to the Grub menu, you should try booting the VM using a 12.04 live cd (or iso), and that should give you access to try to install the patch. This is what I would do if I were in your shoes. The process is pretty straight forward:

1. Boot from live CD
2. Mount system drive
3. Make sure the network is working
4. Install updates as needed

Here are some resources I found through a quick Google search:

1. [help.Ubuntu.com Live CD Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)
2. [help.Ubuntu.com Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
3. [HowToGeek.com Fix Ubuntu System When it Won't Boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/)
4. [WebUpd8.org Fix non-Bootable Ubuntu System due to Broken Update](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html)

Number 4 is probably the one that will be most helpful to you, but I wanted to give you some fall back resources in case you needed some additional info.

## Edit

Per your comment below about the network not working, a work around would be to either add the update package you need to either the Live CD files (just stashing it in a folder, not compiling it into the system) or to it's own ISO and mount it as an additional CD. Then you should be able to manually install the update from inside the Live CD environment.

Comment: I'm able to get into Grub but the rescue option runs into the same issue as the primary OS option. I've looked through some of those links from Google already but will take a look at #4 as I don't think I came across that one.

Comment: Yes, I'm booted from a Live CD at the moment but DNS isn't working even though I have it configured. As such, I'm not able to do any updates. Slowly pushing my way through it.

Comment: I didn't think the Grub rescue option would work, but included it for thoroughness. I really think booting from a live CD is going to be the way to go.

Comment: Trying that route now as I agree it is the best route but it seems to freeze up. I've tried storing the ISO on different storage systems and running the VM from different hosts with the same results. I'm downloading a new Ubuntu Live CD now to see if that will make any difference.

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare. I'm sure you've already thought about this, but can you possibly revert the VM to a backed up copy that was working?

Comment: Have you managed to have any luck with anything?

Comment: I noticed in your screen shots that one of the messages says `scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short`. Per this [Microsoft Technet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Dn770158.aspx) only generation 2 VMs can boot from scsi devices; however, Ubuntu 12.04 can only run in a generation 1 VM. The easiest way to check which generation a VM is is to open a PowerShell prompt (run as admin) and run `Get-VM | Format-List Name,Generation`. If it is setup as a generation 2 machine, you'll have to recreate it as a generation 1 (you cannot change it once the machine is made).

Comment: I ended up getting the VM to boot by selecting an earlier kernel version (3.13.0-61). The problem is supposed to be patched in 3.13.0-62 but it didn't work in that version or 63 even though it did previously. I don't understand why reverting to this earlier version worked but it did. For the record it is a Gen 1 VM and is still running Ubuntu 12.04 so that appears to work. I'll go ahead and select your answer as the correct answer because it did allow me to update the VM even though that wasn't the fix in the end.

Comment: Glad I helped somewhat. All that really matters is you were able to get it fixed. I had downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and setup a Hyper-V VM just to see if I could duplicate your problem, but everything worked fine for me. Anyways, glad to here you got it fixed. I'll add what you did to my answer just to help out anyone else that reads this.